# Windows 10 rear and front audio jacks won't both work

Tags: windows, audio

This whole thing is driving me batty.  I can't believe I have not found anyone in the many, many forums I've checked who understands the situation many of us are facing.  The problem starts with the advice we get that we should just go into the Windows sound settings and select the headphones and adjust the settings.  There is no headphones or speaker/headphones listed, just speakers.  Also, our Realtek Manager does not have the "disable" option in the top right folder.  There is no fault in the connection because when we unplug the speakers at the rear the front jack immediately works with either speakers or headphones.  We want to hook up our speakers at the back and headphones in the front just like always but we can't do it anymore.  All other steps listed in advice posts assume that we will be able to adjust this in Realtek or Windows Sound but the options are just not there.  Again, the headphones are fine and the jack is fine - it is a software problem.  Is there a solution?

Comment: Find and install the appropriate Sound Driver for your PC.

Comment: Yes, had this exact problem for one of my clients. Speakers and headphones would not work together. You inserted the headphone jack for headphones, but it would not work. Installed other drivers, and problem was solved. Windows update reinstalled the wrong drivers again though and the problem came back. A windows update rollback fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, but HP oddly has no software downloads available at all for my 6300.  If anyone can suggest where to get it?

Comment: @bruce HP have not released Windows drivers for the 6300. Try the instructions in [Update drivers in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4028443/windows-10-update-drivers)

Comment: And/Or Download the Realtek generic (I.e non-oem) drivers.  While they are not on the Realtek website there are websites with legitimate links to the drivers.

Comment: Thanks again.  I will look and report back if I find anythiing.  I downloaded the HP Support Assistant and it did recommend a new install of a different build of Realtek, but it still shows only speakers and now the front jacks do not seem to work at all.